# Repository or ServiceAgent in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, dddd

I have a system that talks with the database using repositories. What is the correct definition when it is a remote service? Or better,

Repository is for databases as [...] is for external Web-Services.

*I found in many places about ServiceAgents but I don't know if this is the correct definition.*

Answer (score 1):

In DDD, Repositories represent a virtual collection of entities (aggregate roots in particular).  So, if you have 10M persisted customers, you would work with a repository *as if* it were a collection of all 10M in memory.  Repositories generally only deal with the same types of operations you would find on a collection: Add something, Remove something, Find something in the collection.

If the actual persistence of the data occurs via a Web Service, the implementation of the repository might interact with a Web Service proxy rather than with a database.  The fact that the persistence involves a web service doesn't drive how it should be expressed by your domain however.  That is to say, whether the data is persisted via direct database calls, an ORM, a Web Service, or a courier pigeon is an implementation detail.

Now, if your domain model has dependencies to be facilitated by external services (e.g. credit card validation, address verification, etc.), this should be expressed as a Domain Service in the form of an interface which defines the required operations **in terms of the domain model**.  To be clear, Domain Services are operations which are logically part of your domain, but don't fit cleanly for some reason or another on a given entity or value object.  Behavior facilitated by an external service is just one example of when you might use a Domain Service, so don't think of Domain Services as "the repository pattern for Web Services" or some such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the official term but I'd refer to this as a "Service Proxy".

Comment: Hm, for me Service Proxy means everything that's generated by svcutil. What if you need additional behavior? Most people create wrappers that call the generated proxy classes but with added validation, caching, exception handling. _(That's the term i'm looking for)_

Comment: Perhaps in the dotNet world... Thinking out aloud; I'd use a Repository (since its datastore independent) via a service proxy to access the web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just begging to wrap my head around most of the DDD principles but my understanding is that Repositories are generally used to abstract databases but they could be used to wrap anything that behaves as persistent and/or queryable store. So in short I guess what I'm suggesting is that if your service behaves enough like a database then I don't see any problem with using a repository to abstract access to the entities that it deals with.

Otherwise, if the web service doesn't directly deal with data or behavior that is in your domain, then perhaps your case may be a candidate for an infrastructure level service in your application layer.

If anybody has any objections then please comment as I would like to know if I myself am misunderstanding the intended use of repositories.